# Identity Server 4 logout user from only from the requested client

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

Is it possible to log user out of only a single client? I tried to search online but could not find anything for logging user out from only a specific client.

Comment: What do you mean by logging out? What would you like it to do?

Comment: When the user hits logout, I only want to logout user from one client. Not all the other clients that the user logged in to.

Answer (score 0):

With OAuth2 authentication, you don't log in or out of an application. OAuth2 is about permission delegation using access tokens. There is also the [single sign on](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) (SSO) feature of OpenID Connect (OAuth2 extension).

So you can either log out of the SSO session, which will force you to enter your credentials on the next `/auth` request. Or you can [revoke a token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009) used by a client. But if you have a valid SSO session at the auth server, the client can request a new token without you entering credentials.

So I think you will need to change your requirements (for logging out) to be compatible with OAuth2 / OpenID Connect concepts.